# C# Linux-MonoDevelop how to get Time

Tags: c#, time, monodevelop, floating

I'm trying to figure out how to find how much time is my application running, but all I can find are:

```
Clock()
timersub()
```

and some similar stuff, but I can't use them, ....

what must I include in my code so I can use them?

like I include:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

so I can use:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
```

and if I do:

```
#include <time.h> // I get: Wrong preprocessor directive
```

Also I need floating point since start up and what I do get from:

```
System.DateTime.Now; // - not float but sealed struct
```

Comment: Have You Tried `Stopwatch` its good for keep tracking of time

Comment: "Also I need floating point since start up" - this doesn't really mean much. Do you want the time since the application start up? Or since the device start up? Or the activity start up? And why do you need it in some floating point format?

Comment: Note: `#include <time.h>` isn't C#.  `System.DateTime.Now.Ticks` isn't good?  `n / 10000000M` would give you fractions of a second.  (note, value only updates every `20ms` or so on most systems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use the StopWatch class

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

Do Stuff...

```
sw.Stop();
TimeSpan elapsedTime = sw.Elapsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you want to time an operation you would use the [`StopWatch` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It is available in Mono as well and should work just fine on Linux.